# Cosmos Db not returning all records even though maxItemCount set to -1

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a cosmos database with 50 000 records, but the code bellow only only returns 8356. I thought setting MaxItemCount to -1 would return all of them. How can I achieve that?

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> ReadAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            var entityList = new List<T>();

            var query = _container.GetItemLinqQueryable<T>(requestOptions: new QueryRequestOptions { MaxItemCount = -1 })
               .Where(predicate).OrderByDescending(x => x.TimeStamp).AsQueryable();

            using (var iterator = query.ToFeedIterator())
            {
                entityList.AddRange(
                    await iterator.ReadNextAsync());
            }

            return entityList;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not draining all the query results (missing the check on HasMoreResults):

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> ReadAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    var entityList = new List<T>();

    var query = _container.GetItemLinqQueryable<T>(requestOptions: new QueryRequestOptions { MaxItemCount = -1 })
       .Where(predicate).OrderByDescending(x => x.TimeStamp).AsQueryable();

    using (var iterator = query.ToFeedIterator())
    {
        while (iterator.HasMoreResults)
        {
            entityList.AddRange(
                await iterator.ReadNextAsync());
        }
    }

    return entityList;
}
```

Reference (Intellisense docs): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.feediterator-1?view=azure-dotnet#examples